# Inbuilt deselectAll method not working in multiple Angular mat-selection-list

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular-material2, angular-material-5

I am using angular5 to create multiple `mat-selection-list` in same component.

**list-selection-example.html**

```
 Shoes: 
<mat-selection-list #shoes>
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes" 
                   [value]="shoe">
    {{shoe}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>

<button mat-button  (click)="deselectShoes()">Deselect all Shoes</button>

Cloths: 
<mat-selection-list #cloths>
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let cloth of typesOfCloths" 
                   [value]="cloth">
    {{cloth}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>

<button mat-button  (click)="deselectCloth()">Deselect all Cloths</button>
```

**list-selection-example.ts**

```
export class ListSelectionExample {
  typesOfShoes = ['Boots', 'Clogs', 'Loafers', 'Moccasins', 'Sneakers'];

  typesOfCloths = ['Amaxa', 'Cotton', 'Woolen', 'Nylon'];

    @ViewChild(MatSelectionList) shoes: MatSelectionList;
    @ViewChild(MatSelectionList) cloths: MatSelectionList;


  deselectShoes(){
    this.shoes.deselectAll(); 
  }

  deselectCloth(){
    this.cloths.deselectAll(); 
  }
  ngOnInit(){

  }
}
```

Here is complete code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i3pfu2-dla3rd?file=app%2Flist-selection-example.ts

In this example, `deselectShoes()` method is working as expected.  But `deselectCloth()` is **not** working as expected , its deselecting shoes only.

How we can fix this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how the decorator @ViewChild works and in both variables you are selecting the same element. It should be something like this:

```
@ViewChild('shoes') shoes: MatSelectionList;
@ViewChild('cloths') cloths: MatSelectionList;
```

You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild).

Comment: the problem if you put matoption inside another div i.e flex div it's not working

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can handle it in DOM itself.

Shoes:

```
<mat-selection-list #shoes>
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes" 
                   [value]="shoe">
    {{shoe}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>

<button mat-button  (click)="shoes.deselectAll()">Deselect all Shoes</button>
```

Cloths:

```
<mat-selection-list #cloths>
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let cloth of typesOfCloths" 
                   [value]="cloth">
    {{cloth}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>

<button mat-button  (click)="cloths.deselectAll()">Deselect all Cloths</button>
```